# How to prevent trailing slash on 404ing URLs that end with an extension in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

URLs with extensions resolve properly if they exist on the server, but if they don't exist, they 404, which is to be expected, but then the 404'd URLs get a trailing slash. Is there any way to prevent the trailing slashes on those 404'ing URLs?

Below is the .htaccess file in the root directory of my Wordpress install.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN MainWP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/THIS_PLUGIN_DOES_NOT_EXIST [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END MainWP
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a trailing slash from being added to URLs that end in an extension then it looks like you can just add another *condition* (ie. `RewriteCond` directive) to exclude such files from having a slash appended and redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

So, to prevent URLs that end in `.html` or `.php` from being processed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.(html|php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Note that you will need to clear any intermediary caches, as the previous 301s will have been cached by the browser.

To handle *any extension* (of say between 2 and 4 chars), then you could perhaps do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: No dice. Tried both the first and second, at the very end of my .htaccess file.

Comment: @Mattypants Sorry, the regex should be _negated_! ie. the regex should have a `!` prefix. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ...and make sure you clear your browser cache after making this change.

Comment: Made the change, cleared the cache, but still no dice.

Comment: "at the very end of my .htaccess file" - the above directives should go at the very start of your file, the same place as in your question. (?) These directives just modify what you have already, nothing new. If you put them at the end they will never get processed.